# Choosing Integral Bounds for $P(XY \le \dfrac{1}{2})$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand the solution to the following homework problem:

[image]

[image]

...and here's the solution:

[image]

The integration isn't a problem, but I'm struggling to understand

a) Why the decision was made to use the sum of 2 integrals and

b) Why these specific bounds were chosen.

I'm pretty sure my two questions are related, and that they got the bounds by somehow playing with the inequality, but I don't really follow how they reached this conclusion.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Here is a graph of the region over which you're integrating to help you see why you need to break it up into two integrals: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w3k8itxy4u

Comment: Do you see how the upper $y-$limit changes from $y=1$ on $0\leq x \leq 1/2$ to $y=\frac{1}{2x}$ on $1/2 \leq x \leq 1/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @MatthewHolder Wow ok yeah that helps a lot.  Didn't think to graph it.  Thank you so much!